# Setting up multiple sites on IIS7 with different certs on the same IP and port

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

Scenario:

Site 1 settings -
url: https://www.site1.com
ip: 1.1.1.1
port: 443
cert: *.site1.com

Site 2 settings -
url: https://www.site2.com
ip: 1.1.1.1
port: 443
cert: *.site2.com

IS this even possible on IIS7 or do I have to force one of the sites to go through a different port?

What do the bindings look like in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IIS 7, you can only have one IP per certificate.  With IIS 8, you can use SNI and use multiple certificates per IP.  With only one IP address on you server, you'll need to put site2 onto a different port.

Site 1 settings - url: https://www.site1.com ip: 1.1.1.1 port: 443 cert: *.site1.com

Site 2 settings - url: https://www.site2.com ip: 1.1.1.1 port: 444 cert: *.site2.com